# Ansible / jinja2 list of dicts of lists

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible, yaml, jinja2

I am trying to compose a list from a list of dicts of lists but am failing. Trying to get a list of all peers to r1

Example data yaml:

```
---
conn:
- id: asd
  peers:
  - name: r1
  - name: r2
- id: dsa
  peers:
  - name: r1
  - name: r3
- id: sad
  peers:
  - name: r2
  - name: r4
```

The output should be `[r2,r3]` as r1 only has r2 and r3 as peers. How can I get this list from an ansible task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to explore [JMESPath](http://jmespath.org/):

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    conn:
      - id: asd
        peers:
        - name: r1
        - name: r2
      - id: dsa
        peers:
        - name: r1
        - name: r3
      - id: sad
        peers:
        - name: r2
        - name: r4
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ conn | json_query(qry) }}"
      vars:
        qry: '[*].{p:peers[].name} | [?contains(p,`r1`)].p[] | [?@!=`r1`]'
```

Select `peers[].name` as `p`, select only items which have `r1` as element of `p`, then flatten list and drop any `r1` items effectively leaving only r1 peers as the result.

Comment: Impressive, impressive indeed. It requires jmespath with is not indigenous to ansible. It is a neat working solution none the less. Thanks. I will run with this until someone comes up with another which only requires core ansible modules.